# What is the best way to store Data in parse for ease of searching?

Tags: ios, database, parse-platform

I am developing an iOS application using Parse as my backend that stores book information. I would like users to be able to search the database for the books using either the title of the book, the isbn, or the author. What would be the best way to store the data in parse so that a search function would be able to find the book based on either isbn author or name? I will not know which attribute the user is initially inputing. I would prefer not to use multiple queries if possible. Is there a way for this to be accomplished or will I have to settle for using multiple queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a great example using Swift ([How to Search a Parse Table View](https://medium.com/swift-programming/how-to-search-a-parse-com-table-view-2694ec330523)) and useful blog post from the Parse engineering team ([Implementing Scalable Search on a NoSQL Backend](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/implementing-scalable-search-on-a-nosql-backend/)).

The gist of it is that you will want to store all of the potential search terms in another column. To do that, you will need to:

- [Tokenize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization_(lexical_analysis)) the title, author and isbn
- Remove any [stop words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words) that you don't care about
- Concatenate the search terms together in a column to make it easily searchable (either using regex constraints in Parse or an array of tokens/terms)

One thing to be aware of is that Parse does not have full-text search capabilities built-in. This means that searching is a very costly operation and you will most likely end up using multiple queries/API requests.

Comment: could you point me to a better backend for searching then or is parse still the best option to use?

Comment: I've had this same discussion with Hector Ramos from the Parse Engineering team, [check it out here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/parse-developers/prefix$20regex/parse-developers/OwIMarkWL-U/8VcqqdcYBQAJ). The important bit is the following: "Using a regex query here would be pretty inefficient. Anything other than a prefix regex is not recommended." continued below...

Comment: "Parse's data store is not ideal for this kind of full text search.  An alternative to what is recommended in the blog post would be the following. You can set up an application in another service such as Heroku, which would allow you to create a service that indexes your Listings class in memory. You can use afterSave and afterDelete triggers in Cloud Code to let the Heroku application know when the index needs updating. You can then configure a Cloud Code function to use this service to get a list of object ids that match your search terms."

Answer (score 2):

On Parse you cannot run efficiently full-text search. The only optimized way to search on (partial) strings is with StartsWith, so I would recommend to store Author, Title and ISBN is separate columns and run a single query like this:

```
let userInput = "Ernest"

let byAuthor = PFQuery("Books")
byAuthor.whereKey("author", hasPrefix: userInput)

let byTitle = PFQuery("Books")
byTitle.whereKey("title", hasPrefix: userInput)

let byISBN = PFQuery("Books")
byISBN.whereKey("title", equalTo: userInput)


var query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([byAuthor, byTitle,byISBN])
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (results: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if error == nil {

  }
}
```

Parse now will create 3 indexes internally and will use them when you make the query. Otherwise with regex or other try to full-text search will force Parse to do full scan search and it can be very slow if you have a lot of data.

Comment: This is a valid way to accomplish search but be aware that Parse ***will not*** create 3 indexes internally for this. `hasPrefix` uses regex matching just like `containsString`, the difference is that prefix regex matching is significantly faster than whole-text regex

Comment: @Russell your claim is false, hasPrefix does not uses regex, take a look here:https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries-queries-on-string-values "Use whereKey:hasPrefix: to restrict to string values that start with a particular string. Similar to a MySQL LIKE operator, this is indexed so it is efficient for large datasets". So, yes it will create 3 indexes.

Comment: good catch! You're absolutely right and it's right there in the documentation. I'm actually quite a bit surprised by that and I wonder how they accomplish it from an implementation standpoint. Since the prefix regex is defined as part of a query, I guess they would have to wait until a certain number of queries have been reached before they decide to make a character index on that column. Good to know!